# Can't Read CSV from Download Folder in Android Device C# Unity

Tags: c#, android, file, unity-game-engine, txt

This script generate a txt file in Download folder on Android device.

```
public class WriteCSVInDownloadFolder : MonoBehaviour
{

public TMP_Text Text;

private void Start()
{
    try
    {
        var txtpath = GetDownloadFolder() + "/Test.txt";
        FileStream file = new FileStream(txtpath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Text.text = e.Message;
    }
}

public static string GetDownloadFolder()
{
    string[] temp = (Application.persistentDataPath.Replace("Android", "")).Split(new string[] { "//" }, System.StringSplitOptions.None);

    return (temp[0] + "/Download");
}
}
```

But, when I manually remove this file and execute this script again, I receive an exception: "File already exists"

Therefore , I have tried to use FileMode.Truncate and File.Exists functions, however, I receive another exception: "Could not find file"

Any idea?

**Update 1**

I tried to solve the problem with Dispose() method, but the problem persist.

```
TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(path);
writer.Write("Hello World");
writer.Flush();
writer.Dispose();
```

**Update 2**

I tried to remove residual entries getting Uri, but not working.

```
Uri uri = new Uri(txtpath);
if (uri.IsFile)
{
   string filename = Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);
   Text.text = filename;
   File.Delete(uri.LocalPath);
}
```

**Update 3**

*Current code*

```
private void Awake()
{
  try
  {
    txtpath = FileManager.GetFolder("/Download") + "/Test.txt";

    if (File.Exists(txtpath))
    {
      Text.text = "Exist";
      File.Delete(txtpath);
    }
    else
    {
      Text.text = "Not existe";
      FileStream file = new FileStream(txtpath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    }

  }
  catch (IOException e)
  {
    Text.text = e.Message;
  }
}
```

**Update 4**

New: I tried to use Path.Combine.

Exception thrown: "Access to the path "..." is denied".

```
public class ReadCSVInDownloadFolder : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_Text Text;
    private string path;

    private void Awake()
    {
        try
        {
            path =  Path.Combine("storage","emulated","0","Download", "Test.csv");
            Text.text = File.ReadAllText(path);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { 
            Text.text = e.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure to call `file.Dispose()` (if it has that method) when you're done with it. These kind of problems often are a result of outstanding references waiting to be collected.

Comment: What do you mean with a manual remove?

Comment: This only happens on Android 11+ devices?

Comment: File.Dispose() not working but thank you Stefan for your help

Comment: This issue has only been tested on my personal device (Android 11).
Manual removal means I don't use code for this, I used file explorer, as a non-developer user.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now!

Comment: Have you tried printing out the paths somewhere and check where they actually refer to...? Otherwise I'd say if c# throws exceptions .. it is most probably right ;)

Comment: Thank you derHugo for correcting the tags. Certainly, C# throws exceptions ,but these exceptions don't make sense because File.Exist -> "false" and the exception thrown by FileStream(...) -> "File already exists"

Answer (score 0):

While creating your file it has been indexed by the media store.

So there is an entry for the file in the media store.

There are a bunch of sloppy programmed file managers that delete the file but leave the entry.

So first delete that entry and then you go again.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Do you know how remove these entries?

Comment: Query() the mediastore for this file. If you get its uri you can use delete(uri).

Comment: I tried to remove residual entries getting Uri (you can see my code in the Update 2).
The "filename" variable is displayed correctly and File.Detelete(...) doesn't report any exception. Do you know another way?

Comment: You did not use the media store to obtain an uri. Didnt i suggest you to use the media store? And you can not use the File class to delete.

Comment: Media Store class is a java class and my project is c#. I have tried to integrate Media Store into my code but I can't get it to work.